# Experiencing "Bad Bind Variable" in Oracle Forms

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am new to oracle and I am doing a project on the same
I have the following code and I would like to store the variable 'wid' for my next step but unfortunately I am getting an error

> bad bind variable.

How can i go about it? Any assistance will be highly appreciated

Code:

```
DECLARE
  U_ID VOTERS.V_ID%TYPE;
  PASS VOTERS.PASSWORD%TYPE;
  CURSOR LOGIN_CUR IS
  SELECT V_ID,PASSWORD FROM VOTERS;

BEGIN
  SELECT W_ID INTO :WID FROM VOTERS WHERE V_ID=:V_ID;
  BEGIN
    OPEN LOGIN_CUR;
    LOOP
      FETCH LOGIN_CUR INTO U_ID,PASS;
      IF :V_ID=U_ID AND :PASSWORD=PASS THEN
        OPEN_FORM ('........');
        EXIT WHEN LOGIN_CUR%FOUND;

      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE LOGIN_CUR;
  END;
END;
```

Comment: where did you declared wid? and also you need to declare the variable in correct way, ill try to help.

Comment: hi, thanks..i haven't declared wid because i dont know how to in forms...i only know how to do it in sqlplus and it is done before you run the block. so how do i do it in forms. And even if i declare it here in the block, it doesn't recognize it because i want it as bind

Comment: You have to declare it, you code needs to be adjusted

Comment: Thanks Moudiz, Am open to adjusting it..so how best do you think i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of 'bad bind variable' is here  :

> IF :V_ID=U_ID AND :PASSWORD=PASS

so to resolve you issue you should remove the ':' so your query should be like this

> IF V_ID=U_ID AND PASSWORD=PASS

you already insert data into the variables so no need to use ':' again.

```
DECLARE
U_ID VOTERS.V_ID%TYPE;
PASS VOTERS.PASSWORD%TYPE;
CURSOR LOGIN_CUR IS
SELECT V_ID,PASSWORD FROM VOTERS;

  BEGIN
  SELECT W_ID INTO WID FROM VOTERS WHERE V_ID=V_ID;
  BEGIN
 OPEN LOGIN_CUR;
 LOOP
 FETCH LOGIN_CUR INTO U_ID,PASS;
IF V_ID=U_ID AND PASSWORD=PASS THEN
OPEN_FORM ('........');
EXIT WHEN LOGIN_CUR%FOUND;

END IF;
 END LOOP;
CLOSE LOGIN_CUR;
END;
END;
```

edit---

your cursor should be similar to this, this one works without errors, if yuo have any question please ask :

```
  DECLARE
   U_ID NUMBER(20);
  PASS VARCHAR2(30);
  WID NUMBER(20);
  A NUMBER(20);
  CURSOR LOGIN_CUR IS
    SELECT id INTO A FROM voters;


 BEGIN
 SELECT T_ID INTO WID FROM voters WHERE T_ID = A;
   BEGIN
   OPEN LOGIN_CUR;
  LOOP
  FETCH LOGIN_CUR INTO U_ID;
 IF WID=U_ID THEN
  OPEN_FORM ('........');
   EXIT WHEN LOGIN_CUR%FOUND;

 END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE LOGIN_CUR;
END;
 END;
```

Comment: The cursor part is working fine because am inputting the ':v_id' and 'password' through a form, the error comes in when i want to hold the w_id for a specific v_id to use it for my next step.

Comment: Since am using forms, I want the 'T_ID' to be derived from the result of the inner block variable "A" and then store 'T_ID' for my next form to be able to access it. The problem is storing the value of 'T_ID' for my next form and that's why i had opted for bind. or is there any other way i can store a variables value that can be accessed on a different block/form?

Comment: yes ofcourse you can move data from one procedure to other or block to another but honestly I didnt understand what you want exactly can you explain them in clearer way ?

Comment: Hehe, ok let me try simplify it. The cursor part is for logging in, no big problem there. Only thing i require from the cursor is the user/voter's ':v_id' and use it in the outer block(1st SELECT) to be able to tell which location they registered in i.e 'w_id' then use the 'w_id' to pick only the candidates registered in that location for the voter to vote for. Voting is in a different form hence the need to store the 'w_id' to be able to access it(call it) in the other form(voting). A bit long but Hope you have a better picture of it now

Comment: Do I understand you correct that in the second for  that you are opening you need to access the value in the first form? This is unfortunately not possible in Forms. There are though ways to handle this by e.g. passing parameters to the second form when opening it.

Comment: Hi DJ, I think i framed my question wrong, actually wanted to pass variables between forms and i've found a way using either GLOBAL VARIABLES or PARAMETER LISTS. I think that should work right?

Comment: @user2787280 I am not familar with Forms thats why I am not able to help you

Comment: I should strongly recommend not to use globals even if also that should be possible. A better alternative is passing parameter list when opening the child form.